# Geometric argument that operators on $\mathbb{R}^3$ have an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra

This question came up when trying to trying to find a $3\times3$ real matrix $A$ such that

1. $Ax$ is nonzero for nonzero $x$
2. $Ax$ is orthogonal to $x$ for any $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

We know such a matrix cannot exist because $A$ must have an eigenvalue (thus there is some $x$ such that either $Ax = 0$ or $Ax$ is parallel to $x$)

However,

> Is there a nice, **purely geometric** way to justify that every operator on $\mathbb{R}^3 $ has a (real) eigenvalue?

To clarify: I'm looking an intuitive way to *visualize* why an eigenvalue must exist in this case.  In particular, no polynomials and no determinants are allowed!

Comment: To be clear, you are interested in the existence of a *real* eigenvalue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If $A\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ was a linear map with no eigenvectors, then $x\mapsto Ax/\Vert Ax\Vert$ would give a map on the unit sphere with no fixed points and without taking any point to its antipode, contradicting the [hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hairy_ball_theorem&oldid=402767345#Corollary).

Answer (score 3):

Just using linear algebra but no determinants, the closer to what you ask that I know uses that polynomials of degree 3 with real coefficients have roots:

Let's argue by contradiction, and assume that $A$ has no eigenvalues. First, I claim that any $v$ is contained in a proper $A$-invariant subspace of ${\mathbb R}^3$. This is clear if $v=0$. Otherwise, consider $v,Av,A^2v,A^3v$. They are linearly dependent, so there are real coefficients $a,b,c,d$ not all zero with $(aA^3+bA^2+cA+dI)v=0$.

Now we examine the polynomial $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. If $a\ne0$, $p$ has a real root $r$, and we can write $p(x)=(x-r)(ax^2+ex+f)$ for some real numbers $e,f$. This gives us $(A-rI)(aA^2+eA+fI)v=0$, but $A-rI$ is invertible (since $r$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$), so in fact $(aA^2+eA+fI)v=0$. If $a=0$, then directly we have $(bA^2+cA+dI)v=0$.

This shows that $v$ is contained in a proper $A$-invariant subspace (consider the span $S$ of $v,AV$, and note that the argument above shows that either $A^2v$ is in this span, from which it follows that $S$ is $A$-invariant, or else, the coefficient of $A^2$ above is 0, and in fact $v$ is an eigenvalue, a contradiction).

So we may assume that any non-zero $v$ is in an $A$-invariant *plane* $P_v$. Now, if $w$ is a vector not in $P_v$, then any vector in $P_v\cap P_w$ is mapped by $A$ to another vector in the same line, so $P_v\cap P_w$ is an $A$-invariant line, i.e., $A$ has a real eigenvalue after all.

(Note that I presented the argument as a contradiction for brevity, but it can be rearranged as a direct proof.)

David Milovich found a nice way of extending this argument so we have a short nice "determinant free" proof that $n\times n$ matrices with real entries and $n$ odd admit a real eigenvalue, see this [blog post](http://caicedoteaching.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/403503-eigenvectors-for-operators-on-real-odd-dimensional-spaces/) of mine.

I was interested in this because this is the base case of a nice inductive argument (that actually can be traced back to one of Gauss' first proofs of the fundamental theorem of algebra) that allows us to show that *any* square matrix with real coefficients admits a (perhaps complex) eigenvalue, from which we can deduce the fundamental theorem of algebra. I refer to this in the post above, but it comes from "The fundamental theorem of algebra and linear algebra" by Harm Derksen, American Mathematical Monthly, 110 (7) (2003), 620-623. (The issue is that in that paper, the odd-dimensional case is done by appealing to determinants.)

Comment: Thanks, this is really nice!  But you did cheat and use polynomials ;-)

Comment: Hehe. It would be nice to remove that use, wouldn't it? Not sure it is entirely possible, though.